# Cordova Android FTP or SSH/SCP Plugin

Tags: cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Does anyone know of a Cordova 3.X.X plugin for Android which exposes access to FTP or SSH? I've had no luck in finding one so far, only an ssh plugin for iOS and an ftp plugin for Cordova 2.X.X.